# Default.png for splash screen(iphone)

Tags: iphone, default.png

heyy...how to avoid default.png in foreground task.
  In my app,sometimes its showing default.png while coming from background to foreground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that the system closed your app and it is starting it up again. There is noway te solve this.

When you app is showing up in the fast switch tray (double press the home button) does not mean your app is still running.

Comment: thanx for ur instant reply .Can u elaborate the second line.plzzz tell me what could be reason for above issues?????????

Comment: There is no issue, it build that way.       Apps in the fastswith tray (the tray that ups up when you double click the home button) are apps you have started. The apps in this tray aren't always background, they can be closed as well. If the systeem need more memory it will kill any background app that haven't run in a while or who are using memory.

Comment: thank u very much...its means i have to check memory leaks in my app then it could be improved little bit.

Comment: You should always check for memory leaks, but there is no way to tell when the system will kill your app. When you start an other app that needs lots of memory, iOS will kill any background running app that it can kill until it has enough memory. so the're no default time/date there's no way you can prevent it.

Comment: ohh..i think u misunderstood my another ques,it completely different from first ques...i meant what is the date and time format i.e dd/mm/yyy and for time:HH:MM..these are the time and date formatters..we usually use in code...but if i dont give any formattor then what is default formatt for date and time??

Comment: Please ask this in a new question.